# If statement in AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my code on `1.php` page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        var data;
        data = "action=post";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "2.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data['id'] === 1) {
                    alert('Hi methos get');
                    $('#show').text('methos get');
                }
                if (data['id'] === 2) {
                    alert('Hi methos post');
                    $('#show').text('methos post');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And my HTML code is like this.

```
<button id="click">Click On Me.</button>
<p id="show"></p>
```

The concept is simple: When I click the button the alert box will show some value and the `<p>` will show some value.

This my `2.php` page code:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'get') {
        $array = array("id" => '1', "config" => 'phppost',);
    }
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'post') {
        $array = array("id" => '2', "config" => 'phpget',);
    }
    Header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

I am just now only learning about AJAX and jQuery so please help how to do this.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Match string like if (data['id'] === "1") {}

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: no alert box and value in paragraph showing..

Answer (score 2):

Dear guys both data['id'] & data.id are working the problem is ('1') i didn't give quotation mark for the value, now it is working thanks for all and @Nishan Senevirathna. and my final code is.

```
if (data['id'] === "1") {
     alert('Hi methos get');
     $('#show').text('methos get');
}
if (data['id'] === "2") {
    alert('Hi methos post');
    $('#show').text('methos post');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `JSON` as dataType you will get object so inside `if` you should use something like below

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
if (obj.id === 1) {
     // Your code goes here
} else if (obj.id === 2) {
     // Your code goes here
}
```

So you final code will become like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('#click').click(function(){
                    var data;
                    data = "action=post";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "2.php",
                        data: data,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
                            if (obj.id === 1) {
                                alert('Hi methos get');
                                $('#show').text('methos get');
                            }
                            if (obj.id === 2) {
                                alert('Hi methos post');
                                $('#show').text('methos post');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: i have done the above code but no alert box or text output..

Comment: @PremKumar while printing the data using `console.log(data)` what are you getting?

Comment: @PremKumar try my updated before your `if` statement just use `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`